# Select com checkbox

Tags: php, ajax, script

Galera, minha dúvida é, teria como eu fazer uma consulta no banco mysql e jogar no lugar das cidades ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <style>        
        .combo-label {margin-bottom:.5em;}
    </style>
    <h4 class="combo-label">Selecione as matrículas:</h4>
    <div id="checkboxSelectCombo"></div>

    <script>

        var colors = [
            { Name: "Cidades" },
            { Name: "São Paulo" },
            { Name: "Rio de Janeiro" },
            { Name: "Controle" },
            { Name: "Android" },
            { Name: "Maria" },
            { Name: "joão" },
            { Name: "Plus" },
            { Name: "teste" }
        ];

        $(function () {

            $("#checkboxSelectCombo").igCombo({
                width: 300,
                dataSource: colors,
                textKey: "Name",
                valueKey: "Name",
                multiSelection: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showCheckboxes: true
                },
                dropDownOrientation: "bottom"
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: teria sim, guarde em um array a consulta e depois percorra adquirindo os valores aonde quer

Comment: Pois sou muito inexperiente com ajax e tals, teria como ajudar mais especificamente ? como eu deveria alterar e comentar para mim saber ?

Answer (score 0):

Segue o seu código atualizado, como você pediu.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <style>        
            .combo-label {margin-bottom:.5em;}
        </style>
        <h4 class="combo-label">Selecione as cidades:</h4>
        <div id="checkboxSelectCombo"></div>

        <script>

            $(function () {

                cidades;

                $.get("urlquebuscacidades", function(retorno){
                    /*lá no retorno do .php, deve retornar um objeto ou array, e voce popula sua var no js*/
                    cidades = retorno;
                });

                $("#checkboxSelectCombo").igCombo({
                    width: 300,
                    dataSource: cidades,
                    textKey: "Name",
                    valueKey: "Name",
                    multiSelection: {
                        enabled: true,
                        showCheckboxes: true
                    },
                    dropDownOrientation: "bottom"
                });

            });

        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Pois sou muito inexperiente com ajax e tals, teria como ajudar mais especificamente ? como eu deveria alterar e comentar para mim saber ?

Comment: Blz. Na parte do php é tranquilo para efetuar a consulta e retornar na tela?

Comment: Sim sim, fazer as consultas sim. armazenar em váriaveis, tudo ok, só nao sei passar elas para o script e vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

usa ajax!
exemplo:

```
$.post("insertCidades.php", { cidades: colors }, function(result){
    $("#resultado").html(result); // imprimir o resultado
});
```

no arquivo **insertCidades.php**

```
$cidadesArray = $_REQUEST['cidades'];
// agora inserir na base de dados podes usar um while
```

para testar se esta tudo ok, faz **print_r($cidadesArray)** e na div com id **#resultado** ira conter o array que enviaste

Comment: Olá, obrigado por me ajudarem, mas preciso de mais alguns detalhes ainda estou me aventurando no ajax, nao sei como proceder direito, entendo de php. alguem pode dar mais detalhes ? e separar em arquivos ?

Comment: Pois sou muito inexperiente com ajax e tals, teria como ajudar mais especificamente ? como eu deveria alterar e comentar para mim saber ?